# How to get child entity id after saving it via parent

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

Searched couple of sources but did not get exact scenario. Posting only required code ... Student Entity

```
class Student {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Fee> feeList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFee(Fee fee) {
        fee.setStudent(this);
        this.feeList.add(fee);
    }

}
```

Fee Entity

```
class Fee {
    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;
}
```

Fetching student and adding fee to the parent entity

```
Student student = studentService.findByAdmissionNo(paymentDTO.getAdmissionNo());
Fee f = new Fee();
s.addFee(f);
```

After creating and populating objects am using jpa repository to save student(parent) entity.

```
//fee reference
Fee fee = new Fee(paymentDTO.getAmount(), paymentDTO.getDiscount(), dateOfPayment, paymentDTO.getTransactionID(), paymentDTO.getAcademicYear());

student.addFee(fee);
studentService.save(student);
```

Am able to see Student and Fee records created in DB.
After the above commit, student entity got populated with the Fee reocrds for that students from DB which is expected. But the reference fee which we added to student entity before saving has not updated with **Id** populated as part of above commit, it still has 0(Default value).
I want to fetch Fee id that is created as part of above commit. We can get the id from student entity but the catch is student entity has populate with multiple fee records of that student from DB, so do not know which records is created as part of the current transaction.

Please help.

Comment: You'll want to check the method notes. Save will work differently depending on what you pass into it - if Student exists, Spring will try to determine it exists and use JPA merge. If it can't determine it exists (usually just based on its ID) it will use JPA's persist api on it which has very different functionality than merge. This might be why tutorials constantly use Save and expect the ID to be generated, as persist takes what you give it and manages that instance. Merge on the other hand will return the managed instance. To avoid issues, you should use the instance returned from Save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess that you are using `JpaRepository` in `studentService` to save a student ?

As `JpaRepository` will call `merge()` on a student instance under the cover which then cascade calling `merge()` on a fee instance to insert a DB record to the fee table , and the thing is

```java
Fee mergedFee = entityManager.merge(fee);
```

will not update the Id of the input fee instance but only the Id of the returned fee instance will be updated .As you are now using the `JpaRepository` on the student instance, it will always return a student instance by design and you can never get the fee instance that is returned by `merge(fee)`

It should work if you change to use the `feeRepository` to save the fee :

```java
Student student = studentService.findByAdmissionNo(xxx);
Fee fee = new Fee();
s.addFee(fee);

feeRepository.save(fee);
```

Or use the hibernate specific `saveOrUpdate()` should also work :

```java
Student student = studentService.findByAdmissionNo(xxx);
Fee fee = new Fee();
s.addFee(fee);

Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
session.saveOrUpddate(student);
```

Or just save the `fee` directly but not via the student which is the way that I prefer :

```java
Student student studentService.findByAdmissionNo(xxx);
Fee fee = new Fee();
fee.paidBy(student); //just a setter to set fee.student

feeRepository.save(fee);
```

Comment: I have this approach running in production, but wanted to know if there is any way to get fee id from the approach i posted. Thanks it helped to understand the insights.